# React original vs built

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, node-sass

When I build the original project using `yarn build`, the output is little bit different than the original project. You can see in the images that the images are of different sizes and the text next to it is wrapped. Can you  help me solve this problem.

I am using these frameworks(or libraries)

1. React
2. React Router DOM
3. Node Sass
4. React Reveal

Source Code: [Shop App](https://github.com/sauravk7077/shopApp)

*Build version of Project*
[image: Build version of React app]

*Original Project*
[image: Original Project]

Answer (score 2):

It is probably your webpack configurations. If the links to your css files, `index.scss` especially are not correct, they will not be included and will lead to improper built.

Comment: I am using the default webpack configuration, I don't know how to configure it.